# DataRepository and mybatis support

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have followed the guide react-js-and-spring-data-rest.

https://spring.io/blog/2015/10/28/react-js-and-spring-data-rest-part-5-security

This tutorial use JPA hibernate, I do really like the React/Api design, but I don't wan't to use JPA hibernate DAO, I would like to use Mybatis.

Is there a way to use spring DataRepository with mybatis ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is not possible that way. Of course, you can use `MyBatis-Spring-Boot-Starter` integration which is not far different from Spring Data Repositories. It's not simply than DataRepository can be but not to more... For example one mapper should be:

```
@Mapper
public interface CityMapper {
    @Select("SELECT * FROM CITY WHERE state = #{state}")
    City findByState(@Param("state") String state);
}
```

Then you can inject it as a Bean Repository without implement:

```
@Autowired
private CityMapper cityMapper;
```

Unfortunately, you should do all Crud Operations in the entities you need... this could be tedious, so in de Data Repositories of Spring Data is not need.

The examples are in [MyBatis Reference Documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/), and is much more explained than here.

Comment: The advantage of spring data repository is the suite of tools that can help you manage a rest api (spring-hateoas). So there is just no way? I have seen some home made spring-mybatis-data project but not in a community advanced level

Comment: No, as far as I know, In `MyBatis` you should implement what all these helpful tools do by your hand....